# AngularJS With Multiple Components and CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

As I become more familiar with Angular, and the vast number of modules out there for making an application really shine, I am also becoming overwhelmed at understanding the basic logic of CSS overloading, and how to manage the imports to get the desired behavior.

For instance, I have pulled the following libraries into my Angular application; Boostrap, Bootcards, boostrap-select, font-awesome, and some custom bootstrap-wizard libraries for a modal tab-based wizard.

All of these libraries require being defined in the index.html page of my Angular app (both the CSS files the JS files).  How do you manage the desired behaviors so that one components styles don't override another components styles?  What are the best practices around bringing in multiple components and using them in an Angular app, without negatively affecting the applications previous behaviors?

Comment: Are you having issues with  your js and css files contradicting with other js and css files that might share similar attributes?

Comment: Essentially...  Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 choices:

1. Place more important CSS files AFTER less important ones so the more important override when both have same attribute names.
2. Manually go in stylesheet and change attribute names.
3. Instead of including the stylesheet in index, include it in your html file